# Is it possible to use a triangle strip with the buffergeometry in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

In [the example](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry) for the BufferGeometry, a rectangle is drawn with 18 vertex positions (that is 9 vertex positions, mirrored).

I know WebGL has the Triangle Strip and Triangle Fan type, and I am wondering, is it possible to use these in Three.js so that the vertices do not have to be duplicated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prior to three.js r.112, Triangle Strip and Triangle Fan draw modes are supported.

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

mesh.drawMode = THREE.TriangleStripDrawMode;
//mesh.drawMode = THREE.TriangleFanDrawMode;
//mesh.drawMode = THREE.TrianglesDrawMode; // default
```

Starting with version r.112, only Triangles Draw Mode is supported. You can however use [BufferGeometryUtils.toTrianglesDrawMode()](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.toTrianglesDrawMode) to convert your Triangle Strip or Triangle Fan BufferGeometry into a supported Triangle List geometry.

three.js r.126

Comment: the discussion for the removal of these features is here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/18041